# PostgreSQL group by with sum

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have this code:

```
SELECT  m_warehouse_id, qtyonhand 
FROM    adempiere.rv_storage
WHERE   rv_storage.m_product_id=1000412
GROUP BY m_warehouse_id, qtyonhand
ORDER BY m_warehouse_id;
```

that results in following table:

Now, I want to group by `m_warehouse_id` so it will return only 2 rows 1000000 and 1000001.
qtyonhand will be sumarized and returned as sum. So table should look like:

```
m_warehouse_id    |    qtyonhand
------------------+---------------
10000000          |            0
10000001          |           10
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to use the *aggregate function* `SUM()` and grouped them by `m_warehouse_id`

```
SELECT  m_warehouse_id, SUM(qtyonhand) totalQuantity
FROM adempiere.rv_storage
WHERE rv_storage.m_product_id=1000412
GROUP BY m_warehouse_id
ORDER BY m_warehouse_id;
```

Comment: I spent aged looking the sql in the question and couldn't see why the grouping was failing :-)

Comment: Having the correct answer within 1 minute? That's why you have 33k thank you bro hope you have a great day